# Raising route not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm writing a book on Rails 3 at the moment and past-me has written in Chapter 3 or so that when a specific feature is run that a routing error is generated. Now, it's unlike me to go writing things that aren't true, so I'm pretty sure this happened once in the past.

I haven't yet been able to duplicate the scenario myself, but I'm pretty confident it's one of the forgotten settings in the environment file.

To duplicate this issue:

- Generate a new rails project
- **important**: Remove the `public/index.html` file
- Add cucumber-rails and capybara to the "test" group in your `Gemfile`
- run `bundle install`
- run `rails g cucumber:skeleton`
- Generate a new feature, call it `features/creating_projects.feature`
- Inside this feature put:

This:

```
Feature: Creating projects
  In order to value
  As a role
  I want feature

Scenario: title
  Given I am on the homepage
```

When you run this feature using `bundle exec cucumber features/creating_projects.feature` it *should* fail with a "No route matches /" error, because you didn't define the root route. However, what I and others are seeing is that it *doesn't*.

Now I've set a setting in `test.rb` that will get this exception page to show, but I would rather Rails did a hard-raise of the exception so that it showed up in Cucumber as a failing step, like I'm pretty sure it used to, rather than a passing step.

Does anybody know what could have changed since May-ish of last year for Rails to not do this? I'm pretty confident it's *some* setting in `config/environments/test.rb`, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Wildly stabbing in the darkness, was it the 'show_exceptions' setting? If so, could this be a matter of 'consider_all_requests_local' trying to help us (and failing in this case)?

Comment: I went through the steps provided (cucumber:install instead of cucumber:skeleton) and I can confirm that the tests do pass. Rails 3.0.4 on Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: @TK-421: It's not the `show_exceptions` setting, I set it to `true` and when I run `RAILS_ENV=test rails s` it shows the exception when I go to the controller, but Cucumber doesn't show the exception. I'm pretty sure it's a setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I investigate the Rails source code, it seems like the `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions` middleware that responsible of raising exception `ActionController::RoutingError` is missing in the test environment. Confirmed by running `rake middleware` and `rake middleware RAILS_ENV=test`.

You can see that in https://github.com/josh/rack-mount/blob/master/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb#L152 it's returning `X-Cascade => 'pass'` header, and it's `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions`'s responsibility to pick it up (in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L52)

So the reason you're seeing that your test case is passing because `rack-mount` is returning "Not Found" text, with status 404.

---

I'll git blame people and get it fix for you. It's this conditional here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L159. If the setting is true, the error got translated right but we got error page output. If it's false, then this middleware doesn't get loaded at all. Hold on ...

---

**Update**: To clearify the previous block, you're hitting the dead end here. If you're setting `action_dispatch.show_exceptions` to `false`, you'll not get that middleware loaded, resulted in the 404 error from `rack-mount` got rendered. Whereas if you're setting `action_dispatch.show_exceptions` to `true`, that middleware will got loaded but it will rescue the error and render a nice "exception" page for you.

Comment: Ok it's this legendary commit. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d898a4ba425a201827f07a5bb11c8c6bf85159b8 ... best part? It has been edited at the time frame you provided!

Comment: It seems like that commit is supposed to make errors be raised, rather than rendered.  Did it somehow do the opposite?

Comment: @Andy so it raises the error for every other case, except for this edge case that `X-Cascade => pass` which was handled by that particular middleware. Must be something that they had overlooked.

Comment: Nice find!  Glad it's committed now :)